# Linear algebra and geometric insight: a rigorous approach to vector spaces, matrices, and linear applications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, reference-request, soft-question

I'm searching for some material (books or lecture notes) that extensively uses a geometric approach to explain the meaning of the concepts related to vector spaces, matrices, and linear applications presented in an undergraduate course in linear algebra (for instance, the basis of a vector space, the orientation of a vector space, the determinant of a matrix, and so on). Nice pictures and graphics is a plus.

Comment: There is a certain amount of tension between rigor and geometric insight. "Rigorous" means amenable to algorithmic checking of the correctness of the logic. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There are tons of textbooks doing exactly this, the mother of them all being Halmos' *Finite dimensional vector spaces* (1958).

Comment: i find strang's linear algebra textbook very helpful to see geometrically, for example i like the way he presents the four space associated with a linear transformation.

Comment: I came in with Halmos's bookin my mind, and found it already stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Two and a half hints* from my side:

> - [Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387941282) from Klaus Jänich is an introductory text which presents a short and concise introduction to the most important concepts.

All books from Jänich written for undergraduates contain many clarifying pictures (I suppose his book  [Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461270189) is the most *famous* of them). Some students may also appreciate his sometimes unconventional style (I was one of them).

Each chapter finishes with a section of exercises to check your understanding. A few sections are explicitly dedicated for mathematicians while other sections are written with focus for physicians.

But be aware,  you probably will *not find all* the topics you need due to the restricted length of the book.

> - [Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387900934) from Paul Halmos is my second hint for you and complementary to Jänich's book.

@Christian Blatter entitles this book the *mother of modern books about Linear Algebra* in the comment section and he's absolutely right. At the end of the Preface section Halmos gave credits to *John von Neumann*. He designates him as one of the originators of the *modern spirit and methods* which inspired him to present and teach the way he did in this book.

I deeply appreciate his books written from one of the great  in a clear and easy to follow style. In order to get an impression of his writings I recommend his essay [How to write mathematics](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eazoff/courses/halmos.pdf).

> - The *half hint* is a supplement to Halmos book, namely his [Linear Algebra Problem Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883853221) which provides completely elaborated solutions to about 160 problems. If you are interested in it you may have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949236/exercise-books-in-linear-algebra-and-geometry/965847#965847).

Comment: Once again, thank you. I've been already working through Halmos' Linear Algebra Problem Book and it has been a good reading. I will surely try the other two.

Comment: @Dal: Hi, Dal! Your response was amusing. I didn't recognise that you have posted the question. :-) Thanks for the bounty! Regards,

Comment: It is curious that Fischer's very second rate textbook got translated. His presentation of the tensor product is so wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a Choquet's "[Neue Elementargeometrie](https://www.amazon.de/Elementargeometrie-Choquet-Gustave-Dieter-R%C3%B6dding/dp/B00L1SK500)" from 1970. There seem to be only French and German versions of the book, though.